# Antialiasing( add smoothness) when masking a window for round-corner in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt5

I am making an window where i want to have round corners,I know it can be very easy by setting

```
        self.mainframe=QFrame(self)
        self.mainframe.setStyleSheet("background:blue;border-radius:25px")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainframe)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

[image: This is the result]

It has nicely rounded, I mean corners are smooth(Antialiased).
But I dont want to go with this for a reason.I have a second option that i set a mask using **QPainterPath** in **resizeEvent**.

Here is the code

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
        path = QPainterPath()
        print(self.rect())
        path.addRoundedRect(QRectF(self.rect()),25, 25,Qt.AbsoluteSize)
        reg = QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon())
        self.setMask(reg)
```

[image]

But its corners are not smooth means **Antialiased**.

Here is my complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,  QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainterPath, QRegion
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFrame

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(600,400)
        self.mainframe=QFrame(self)
        self.mainframe.setStyleSheet("background:blue;border-radius:25px")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainframe)
        # self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        path = QPainterPath()
        print(self.rect())
        path.addRoundedRect(QRectF(self.rect()),25, 25,Qt.AbsoluteSize)
        reg = QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon())
        self.setMask(reg)     

   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is There any way to achieve that.I mean to look like 1st one?

Comment: "But I dont want to go with this for a reason". *What* reason?

Comment: cause qtmediaplayer wont support translucent background to render/play.

Comment: The problem is that you cant use antialiasing when using `setMask` As far as I know that is not solvable when using `setMask`

Comment: Ok, the next time you should remember to specify those reasons in the question, as it is a very specific use case and it is not obvious to the reader. Since QMediaPlayer doesn't support translucent background you're stuck with setMask, which uses a *bitmap* intented as *binary* values for the mask: they are just True or False, so, no there's no way to have antialiasing using setMask.

Comment: but this kind of masking [check](https://stefan.sofa-rockers.org/2018/05/04/how-to-mask-an-image-with-a-smooth-circle-in-pyqt5) have option for antialiasing.will this help me?

Comment: @Raj1234 No. That is a completely *different* type of masking, as it uses QPainter with a QImage (which supports antialiasing since it's using a 32bit color format). Again, `setMask` does **NOT** support antialiasing, as it uses binary based bitmaps.

Comment: Btw, as already suggested in other answers given to you, there's no benefit in using a QMainWindow for what you're doing, just use a plain QWidget, a simple boxed layout, and add the QFrame to it.

Comment: Ok.Thanks!!!.Then,I need to adjust with that.May Qt Fixes that Bug in the Later version.

Comment: @Raj1234 This is not a bug, it's the desired behavior, as masking *is* based on bitmaps. It is possible that in future (major) releases there will be better support, but the problem comes from a mix of platform ui backend and video management, which cannot be easily (and cross-platform-ly) solved. Video displaying is *not* as immediate as it might seem. Note that there's a possibility: you could use a QGraphicsView and add a [QGraphicsVideoItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsvideoitem.html) to its scene.